# Azure App Service Architecture understanding: IP-based SSL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Regarding this MSDN article; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270

**Scale Unit Network Configuration** sections has below sentences;

> In the case of IP-based SSL, a given application is allocated a dedicated IP address for only inbound traffic, which is associated with the Cloud Service deployment. Please note: Front ends terminate SSL connection for all HTTPS requests for all applications and any type of certificate. The front end then forwards the request to the designated worker for a given application.

But, when `Please note: Front ends terminate SSL connection for all HTTPS requests for all applications and any type of certificate` happens?

- Is this happened right after that we configure IP-based SSL?
- or, is this happened to all traffics always under IP-based SSL?
- or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens for all traffics. All https traffic irrespective of whether you are using a ip-based SSL, SSL cert from external CA's or using internal Azure SSL (azurewebsites.net) the SSL traffic is terminated at the front-end each scale unit has and from front-end to worker will always be http traffic. In return the same is encrypted back at front-end before traffic goes out using the SSL uploaded for specific domain/azure provided SSL cert.

Comment: The document describes _Frond End_ is just layer-7 LB simply. So in Azure AppService, can we say that SSL encrypt/decrypt happens at _Front End_ with given certificate?

Comment: Yes, front end does both SSL termination as well load balancing